# Lookup matching array oject properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing, match

I have two arrays:

`var scores = [{ name: "Bob", score: 19 }, { name: "Harry", score: 27 }, { name: "Janelle", score: 35 }];`

`var ranks = [{ name: "Bob", rank: 3 }, { name: "Harry", rank: 2 }, { name: "Janelle", rank: 1 }];`

I want to merge the two arrays and add "rank" to all the corresponding arrays without repeating "name". Just like INDEX MATCH in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go thru both arrays and build one object with keys as unique `name` and accumulate values. Use `Object.values` to values as an array.

```js
var scores = [
  { name: "Bob", score: 19 },
  { name: "Harry", score: 27 },
  { name: "Janelle", score: 35 }
];

var ranks = [
  { name: "Bob", rank: 3 },
  { name: "Harry", rank: 2 },
  { name: "Janelle", rank: 1 }
];

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const res = {};
  [...arr1, ...arr2].forEach(item =>
    Object.assign(res, { [item.name]: { ...res[item.name], ...item } })
  );
  return Object.values(res);
};

console.log(merge(scores, ranks));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function named `mergeArrays` that accepts the source array, the destination array, and a key to match array items with. Using `Array.map` iterate through the `source` array, then when a `destination` array item with the same `key` value is found, assign the object's values and return the map. Note that this will not only assign `rank` to the `source` array, but all the values in the `destination` array. Seeming as how in the example `rank` is the only differing property it should not be a problem.

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/SamePreemptiveRuby)

```
var scores = [
  { name: "Bob", score: 19 }, 
  { name: "Harry", score: 27 }, 
  { name: "Janelle", score: 35 }
]

var ranks = [
  { name: "Bob", rank: 3 }, 
  { name: "Harry", rank: 2 }, 
  { name: "Janelle", rank: 1 }
]

const mergeArrays = (source, destination, key) => {
  return scores.map((score) => {
    let rank = ranks.find((rank) => rank[key] === score[key])
    return Object.assign(score, rank)
  })
}

console.log(mergeArrays(scores, ranks, 'name'))
```